# How append row to table in string variable

Tags: javascript, string, append, row

I need to create a table by string variable.
I want append row to string by format of tabs.
How do you do that?

```
var textSummary = "DATE              USER                COMMENT               ";
```

How add row to string and keep on this template?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish but from what I understand you are trying to create table row entries using string variables. Take a look at this code which dynamically creates table row elements and creates table entries using string variables:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var numOfRows = 5
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfRows - 1; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');

    var textSummary1 = document.createTextNode('Date' + i);
    var textSummary2 = document.createTextNode('User' + i);
    var textSummary3 = document.createTextNode('Comment' + i);


    td1.appendChild(textSummary1);
    td2.appendChild(textSummary2);
    td3.appendChild(textSummary3);

    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

It creates 4 rows with 3 columns each for Date, User, Comments. you can change the number of rows by changing the numOfRows variable in the loop. You can change the parameters for document.createTextNode to whatever your data is.